# Is "Use a different program" an answer?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I recently came across a question, which I will paraphrase here, since I don't think it's worth linking to and subjecting it to the meta-effect.

> I'm using vi, and some of my commands are mapped incorrectly. What could be causing this issue, and how do I reset it to the default setting?

A user posted this answer:

> This looks like you are using the classic "VI" instead of "VIM (VI IMproved)". If you are root on the machine try installing VIM. I experience this behaviour on Ubuntu every time after a fresh os install.

Now, even though I agree with them, (vim is *far* better than vi) I thought this is clearly NAA. I flagged it as NAA, but it was declined, stating:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer.

I think this decline was wrong. This isn't a technical inaccuracy, because it isn't an answer. This answer didn't attempt to answer the post. If I ask:

> How do I do X in Y?

And someone answers:

> You shouldn't being using Y. You should use Z instead.

That doesn't answer the question of how to do X. Or for example, if someone says:

> This C code is creating a memory leak. How can I fix it?

and I answer:

> You should use Java instead. Java has less memory leaks.

This is clearly NAA.

Was my flag correct?

Comment: Yeah, "use Java instead" would not be an answer. But "you should allocate on the stack instead of the heap" would be an answer. Don't make it too complicated. "Use this similar, improved version of vi that does exactly what you want" is clearly an answer to the question.

Comment: Well, obviously, any vi/vim users should be flagged as borderline insane :)

Comment: @MartinJames <C-x> that really hurts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the different program is as close as vim is to vi, I think this is okay. No, it won't work for everyone, maybe not even the author of the question, but it will work for some people, so it should *at least* not be deleted. This is basically the same as pointing out that a problem was fixed in a later version. It might not be the best answer for everyone, but it does attempt to answer the question.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right. While we're on the subject, (even though it wasn't a post that should be flagged) is it even worth it to flag really old questions/answers?

Comment: @DJMcGoathem Yes, if you see something that should be flagged, ignore the age of the post and flag it.